# Add ImageView programatically with own onTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a button that I want to create a ImageView everytime I am pressing it, this ImageView can have his own onTouchListener right ?
I have a button create new and everytime I press it a ball will appear on the screen that I will be able to move it, when I finnish it moving when I press New again another ball will appear on the screen with the same properties and ability to drag and drop.I am asking because I have problem creating a ImageView programatically for example:

```
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageView asds = new ImageView(this);
                asds.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.element_wall);

                asds.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

For example, this is not working how it should.Thank you for the time acording reading this.

Comment: What's the part that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use setOnTouchListener outside setOnClickListener.

Secondly assign each imageview a unique tag using setTag() method and using image.getTag() you can get the tag and once you get the image with unique tag you can set OnTouchListener on the particular imageview

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You need to add the view to one of the `ViewGroup`s on screen. For instance, if you have a FrameLayout containing all your views, you would do something like:

   ```
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
   FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewByid(R.id.container);
   frameLayout.addView(imageView);
   ```
2. Since you are creating the ImageView inside of an anonymous inner class, the `this` keyword refers to the anonymous inner class, not the Activity. You need to qualify the `this` keyword with your Activity's name, e.g.

   ```
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
   ```

Comment: I don't know but it's not working creating like you sayd ( I replaced MyActivity with activity_main and it's not working.

Comment: Is `activity_main` the name of your Activity class? That sounds more like a layout name.